# Access to NTFS partition WITH authentication

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, ntfs, policykit, udisks

xubuntu allows by default the mounting of an ntfs partition without requesting any kind of authorization.
How can I force it to request authorization (fhe same way that synaptic requires authorization to make changes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP found the answer (and posted it in a comment).

> I solved it!
>
> I try to find "udisk" in synaptic and a package named
>   "policykit-desktop-privileges" is result from this search.
>
> This package also install a file in:
>   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
>
> I edited first part of this file, com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla:
>
> [Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
>   Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
>   Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smar‌​t*;[...]org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab;
>   ResultActive=auth_admin

– [Fabio](/users/106254/fabio) Nov 7 '12 at 17:59